# ASP.NET MVC: How to call custom Html Helper from a controller method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to write a controller method that returns an ActionResult.

In this method, i would like to:
1. call an HTML helper method 
2. Capture and store the HTML helper's rendered HTML in a string 
3. Return the method with the rendered HTML wrapped as a JSON

How do i call the Html Helper method from my controller method? Simply using the static class HtmlHelper does not work.

Comment: What is this HTML helper that you are trying to call? I bet there's an alternative.

Comment: Why return the HTML as JSON?  Why not just return it as HTML and use a partial view?

Comment: @Darin: after thinking about the issue more, there is a better design alternative. For my situation, i think it's best to just to refactor the html helper as an action method.

@sean: I need to return it as a JSON because i need to return an error check variable and notify the client of any errors.

Comment: I knew there's a better alternative. There are always better alternatives rather than calling HTML helpers in a controller action :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var helper = new HtmlHelper<TModel>(new ViewContext(), new ViewPage());
```

Or, if that doesn't work, you could try this.

```
Stream filter = Stream.Null;
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filter);
var viewContext = new ViewContext(this.ControllerContext, 
    new WebFormView("MyView"), 
    new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData), 
    new TempDataDictionary(), writer);
var helper = new HtmlHelper<TModel>(viewContext, new ViewPage());
```

Just replace TModel with the type of your model.